# Meaning of "co-opt" in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

Below is a quote from Matt Lewis's writing:

> "Instead of kicking Trump while he's down, these Republicans think they can finesse and **co-opt** their way to the top. They've been making the same mistake for years. They think Trump will eventually reward loyalty — that the old man will retire and turn the store over to you to run. It never happens."

What does the "co-opt" mean in this sentence? Does it mean contrive to do something?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/co-opt should be a start

Comment: @JamesK I have looked up dictionaries, but those meanings don't look to fit in here. What do you think?

Comment: Your recent edit was removed. Please see this help page for what to do if your question doesn't get answers: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary definitions I found were correct, but didn't give the full flavour of the term.

In your example, as in general, "co-opt" means, getting your opponents and enemies onto your side so you can benefit from their power. This is in contrast to fighting against them or getting rid of them. To "*co-opt your way to the top*" means to co-opt people who are in power to get yourself to the top, rather than fighting against them.

A common example is when there's a badly behaved kid in a classroom who has a lot of influence over the other kids. Rather than berating or punishing the child, the teacher talks to them privately, acknowledges their power, and asks for their help, giving them a desired role in the classroom. This reducies the kid's investment in ruining the classes, and increasing their investment in the success of the teacher. If it works, the teacher has *co-opted* the badly behaving student.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm still a little confused. In your example, the teacher co-opted the badly behaving student. But in my sentence, these Republicans co-opt their **way** instead of Trump or their enemies. I don't know how to understand it. And I'm a learner, please bear me if my question is silly.

Comment: I've added a sentence to my first paragraph. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: That is very clear, thank you!

Comment: And in general, to ***verb* your way *somewhere*** means to do *verb* to get to *somewhere*, as in, "She pushed her way out of the crowd."

Comment: Oh, I see! I do know this one but I didn't notice these two are in the same form! Really helpful, thank you again!

Comment: Happy to help you!